# list expander (css problem)

Tags: jquery, expander

here is the last site I work on.... http://www.nettoyants-ecolo-lemieux.com/

in ie6 when you click on the LAURENTIDES link (first on the right) the colum jump under the first even if it is flot.... in firefos.. it fine...

Anybody have a clue how to fix that

thanks in advance

Comment: STOP SUPPORTING IE6.... LET IT DIE!!!!!!!

Comment: @Jason, when you find a customer willing to pay for a website that doesn't work for 1 out of every 5 visitors, let me know. In the mean time, I'll keep supporting IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your jquery code - it's a matter of IE's poor/wrong CSS support. Try removing:

```
position: relative;
```

from #contentleft and it should work fine;)